# Adding profile2 profile to panel in drupal7

Tags: drupal, drupal-panels

I am building a social networking site with drupal 7.32.I am using Profile2 module for user profiles.I have added fields to the default profile type.Now, I want to display the profile on the right side of the two column stacked layout of the panel.After creating the panel pages and on the last screen where the layout appears when I click on the gear and add content the next screen asks for node id which I am not able to fill.What should be the node id ? I am in a fix.

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Page manager? Add the "currently logged in user" to the context and you should get the ability to add personal information to the page.

Another way to go is to create a view with a contextual filter to the currently logged in user. The view can then later be displayed on the panels page (without context).